# Need help in adding support for Greek Language characters in a Script

Tags: string, encoding, character-encoding, julia

I have to Implement fonts for more languages for [SenseHat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaBerry/SenseHat.jl/blob/master/src/text.jl)
The current set of fonts available within the SenseHat library are limited to English/Latin characters.

I gotta implement font shapes for other languages.

Current font definitions for English are [here](https://github.com/JuliaBerry/SenseHat.jl/blob/218cad53556d2637e87b631d4539a424ff92eba1/src/text.jl#L63)

[image]

I can't seem to understand in which encoding these characters are represented. Can someone tell that ? Also, where can I find/generate such Boolean representations of Greek Characters.

Thanks.

Comment: We need some context here. What exactly are we looking at…? Any hint? What language or tool produced this?

Comment: @deceze Added more info. The language written is Julia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for the SenseHat add in board for Raspberry Pi, the board has an LED display grid which is 8X8 pixels in area. Since the blank char is all zeros in the first line of your table,  the table is a table of the states of the grid to light the LED display in order to display a character.

You may need a sheet of graph paper to rough out what your Greek alphabet will look like if reduced to displaying on an 8x8 pixel grid. If you can find an 8x8 Unicode font, you can look at the Greek alphabet Unicode pages for hints. For example, https://docs.rs/font8x8/0.1.1/font8x8/constant.GREEK.html, and translate the integers to bit arrays:

bits = UInt8.(digits(integer, base=2))